# Why does my hamburger stop working after the first click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hamburger icon that animates open and close respitvely with my sidenav. I had to put functionality in that would create a delay so the user wouldn't doubleclick as well as giving the hamburger to animate closed when clicking outside of its area (this was because the sidenav could close when clicking anywhere on the page).

The button delay seems to work fine, however my hamburger will not animate again after the first go around. Could someone help me figure out why?

```
$hamburger.on("click", function(e) {
        $(".hamburger").toggleClass("is-active");
        event.preventDefault();
        var el = $(this);
        el.prop('disabled', true);
        var time = setTimeout(function(){el.prop('disabled', false); }, 1000);

        $(document).on("click", function(e) {
            if($hamburger.hasClass("is-active")){
                clearTimeout(time);
                $hamburger.toggleClass("is-active");
            }
        });
    });
```

**UPDATE**

I moved that document onclick out of the function and changed it to window onclick. And then gave the hamburger the same delay as the duration of the animation of the slider so that it would only be clicked once the slider was full out, this helped avoid some other issues I was having. Thank you for your help everyone.

```
$hamburger.on("click", function(e) {
        $hamburger.toggleClass("is-active");
        event.preventDefault();
        var el = $(this);
        el.prop('disabled', true);
        setTimeout(function(){el.prop('disabled', false); }, 300);
    });

    $(window).click(function() {
        if($hamburger.hasClass("is-active")){
            $hamburger.removeClass("is-active");
        }
    });
```

Comment: are you using animate.css?

Comment: Can you provide a working example or fiddle (with your html)?

Comment: You're attaching a click event on document each time your hamburger is clicked, not sure you want to do that.

Comment: Thanks, not sure what I was thinking. You go t me on the right track.

Comment: If you've found a solution, please post an answer and mark it as answered.